# Login via spring security don't work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I add to my application the following configuration class for the spring security:

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/publico/**", "/erro/publico/**", "/bootstrap/**", "/extras/**", "/jquery/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/acesso/login").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/processaLogin").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("login")
            .passwordParameter("senha")
            .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/processaLogout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/acesso/login").permitAll();
}
```

which in the moment doesn't work (after I enter my login credencials, back to login page instead go to start page).

My CustomAuthenticationProvider is this:

```
@Autowired
private UserDetail usuario;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication arg0) throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate");

    UserDetails user = usuario.loadUserByUsername(arg0.getName());

    if(user.getPassword().equals(arg0.getCredentials())) {
        System.out.println("yes");
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
        return auth;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("not");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

My CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    SavedRequest savedReq = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.ACCESS_DENIED_403);
    if (savedReq == null) {
        if(arg2.getAuthorities().contains("admin")) {
            System.out.println("admin");
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/privado/admin");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("customer");
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/privado/customer");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("access_denied");
        response.sendRedirect(savedReq.getRedirectUrl());
    }
}
```

My CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure");
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/erro/login");
}
```

Anyone can see what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more tests I finally figure out what this problem: I'm just missing the 'method=post' in the login page. Now it's working fine.